# Why AWS auto scaling lunch configuration doesn't allow to encrypt the root volume?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ami, amazon-ebs

I'm using a community based AMI as part of auto scaling launch configuration and I need to encrypt the EBS volumes. When I try to create the launch configuration the `Encrypted` property for the root volume is set to `No` and I cannot change it:

[image]

But If I try to launch an ec2 instance directly using that AMI it does provide the Encryption option in the storage section:

[image]

Why is like this? How can I apply encryption to my launch configuration?

Answer (score 1):

It's because the AMI you are using for the Launch config doesn't have encryption enabled. Hover the 'I' and read the tooltip: `Volumes that are created from encrypted snapshots are automatically encrypted, and volumes that are created from unencrypted snapshots are automatically unencrypted. If no snapshot is selected, you can choose to encrypt the volume.`

You can either add a new volume and encrypt that, alternatively create the AMI with an encrypted volume.

Hope this helps.

EDIT 
As  Michael - sqlbot - has pointed out, as it is a community AMI, you will should to create a copy of the AMI, to encrypt and protect against withdrawal.

Comment: Since this is a community AMI, the advice should be to create a copy of it for use in your environment rather than using it directly in the launch config, because you can't control whether or when the owner/creator of the AMI might withdraw it, at which point you have a big problem if your ASG depends on it.  Encrypt your copy and the instances will follow.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot: If the AMI has encryption disabled, why does it offer encryption when launching a single instance, but not when creating a launch configuration? 
I experience the same behavior with the AWS Ubuntu 18.04 AMI.

Comment: @FlorianPfisterer I don't know whether it's simply because that's the way they designed it or whether perhaps there are internal performance considerations that might come into play if a very large number of new snapshot-originated volumes with newly applied encryption needed to be spun up. Encrypting a volume created from an unencrypted snapshot means all the data from the snapshot must be read and encrypted and written to the new volume, and this processing work presumably has to be done once for each volume... while for already-encrypted snapshots, that work has already been done, once.

Comment: Okay, thank you very much for the follow-up explanation! @Michael-sqlbot

Answer (score 0):

You can use AWS [Launch Templates](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/LaunchTemplates.html) instead of Launch Configurations. They give you additional control (e.g. root volume encryption):

[image]